# Variables while reading a file with multiple rows in a list - python or shell

Tags: python, shell

I am looking to do this in python or a basic shell script.

I have a file with multiple entries that I would like to manipulate its data and store them in variables.

The file has rows with multiple columns. The first column is a person's name (i.e., Joe, Mary, etc). The second (after the comma) is an ID. I would like to store each ID into a variable and then construct some links as shown below. The problem is that one name can have only one ID or multiple, as you can see below:

```
Joe, 21142 21143 21909 24125
Mary, 22650 23127
John, 24325
Mike, 24683 24684 26973
```

How can I store each value in the "second column" into a variable so I can then construct  links like this:

```
http://example/Joe/21142
http://example/Joe/21143
http://example/Joe/21909 
http://example/Joe/24125
http://example/Mary/22650 
http://example/Mary/23127
```

Thank you in advance!

- Omar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be done with `GNU awk`

```
awk -F'[, ]+' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) print "http://example/"$1"/"$i }' input.txt
http://example/Joe/21142
http://example/Joe/21143
http://example/Joe/21909
http://example/Joe/24125
http://example/Mary/22650
http://example/Mary/23127
http://example/John/24325
http://example/Mike/24683
http://example/Mike/24684
http://example/Mike/26973
```

Or in Python

```
s = '''Joe, 21142 21143 21909 24125
Mary, 22650 23127
John, 24325
Mike, 24683 24684 26973
'''
from StringIO import StringIO
from contextlib import closing
with closing(StringIO(s)) as f:
    for line in f: 
            x, y = line.split(',')
            x = x.strip()
            y = y.strip().split()
            leader = 'http://example/{}'.format(x)
            print '\n'.join('{}/{}'.format(leader, z) for z in y)
```

Answer (score 1):

bash answer: the read command operates line-wise over the file and grabs comma-or-whitespace-separated words into an array

```
while IFS=$', \t' read -ra words; do
    for ((i=1; i<${#words[@]}; i++)); do
        printf "http://example/%s/%s\n" "${words[0]}" "${words[i]}"
    done
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myfile = open('input','r')
link = dict()
for line in myfile:
    line = line.split(",")
    IDs = line[1].split()
    link[line[0]]=IDs
myfile.close()

for name in link.keys():
    for ID in link[name]:
        print ''.join(["www.whatever.com/",name,"/",ID])
```

Answer (score 0):

First off since you are reusing the url, its better to create a reusable template. Next since a name could have many ids, you need to run another loop inside the main loop to generate each url. Below code should work.

```
url_template = "http://example/%s/%d"
with open("input.file") as f:
    for line in f:
        name  = line.split(',')[0].strip()
        n_ids = line.split(',')[1].strip().split(' ')
        for n_id in nids:
            print url_template % (name, nid)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I get this error: `$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    with open("test.file") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.file'`

Comment: hey, you have to put your filename there. What is your filename? Did you even understand my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess i'm late to this party, might as well share:

```
lines  = '''Joe, 21142 21143 21909 24125
Mary, 22650 23127
John, 24325
Mike, 24683 24684 26973'''

    linesList = lines.split("\n")
    for line in linesList:
        lineList = line.split(",")
        lineName = lineList[0];
        lineNumbers = lineList[1].split(" ")
        for lineNumber in lineNumbers:
            if lineNumber.isdigit():
                print("http://example.com/" + lineName + "/" +lineNumber)
```